# Get Length of Highlighted Text Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How can I get the number of characters of a highlighted text in Tkinter text boxes?

I tried subtracting the starting and ending points with:

```
sel_first = float(self.text_box.index("sel.first"))
sel_last = float(self.text_box.index("sel.last"))
```

but since there can be an infinite amount of characters in that line, it didn't work.

Comment: What sort of length? Number of characters? Number of pixels?

Comment: Number of charcters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are not floating-point numbers, so you can't do floating point math with them. They are strings composed of a line number and character number separated by a period.

If you want the number of characters between two indexes you can use the `count` method:

```
nchars = self.text_box.count("sel.first", "sel.last", "chars")[0]
```

Note: this returns a tuple, because it can return the count of multiple things at once ("chars", "displaychars", "displayindices", "displaylines", "indices", "lines", "pixels", and "ypixels")

Comment: Bryan Oakley you are pro